# Is there open-source code for making 'link preview' text and icons, like in facebook?

Tags: php, jquery, facebook, javascript

In facebook, when you share a link, a neat little preview is created with an image headline, and text excerpt. Here's an example..

[image: Example Link]

Does anyone know if there's any open-source code (pref. php & javascript/jquery) that can generate something like this? Or should I just write it myself..

Cheers!

Comment: Here's some that I haven't tried that might do what you want: https://github.com/brenden/node-webshot , https://github.com/cjdell/webpage-preview , https://github.com/Ekito/bootstrap-linkpreview or check the answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24054691/how-to-create-link-previews-like-in-facebook-linkedin

Comment: How is this question "not constructive" when it has over 30 upvotes?

Comment: The way to answer these questions is to search on GitHub for your topic, e.g. "link preview", and narrow down the search to your preferred language, e.g. JavaScript. Here's [such a link](https://github.com/search?l=JavaScript&q=link+preview&type=Repositories).

Comment: I released a node.js library which uses puppeteer [link-preview-generator](https://www.npmjs.com/package/link-preview-generator).

Comment: Another option I found in my searches (I'm not affiliated with either site). Article with example: https://codingislove.com/generate-link-preview-webapp/ The service: https://www.linkpreview.net/

Answer (score 15, accepted):

After a bit of Googling I found **[this](http://www.99points.info/2010/07/facebook-like-extracting-url-data-with-jquery-ajax-php/)** for you.

It should take you through the steps on how to create something similar to Facebook share previews.

Comment: Can you please tell me how it can be achieved in python?

Comment: You can see this demo in real action at http://wallscriptclone.com/

Answer (score 14):

Embedly provides a powerful API to convert standard URLs into embedded videos, images, and rich article previews.I Searched and found an easy way to do it.

Just make a Get request to http://api.embed.ly/1/oembed?url=YOUR-URL . You will find everything in json Format.

Comment: This is neither code nor open source

Answer (score 4):

Have a look at [bootstrap-linkpreview](https://github.com/Ekito/bootstrap-linkpreview) js library as well. It should fit exactly your needs.

Comment: One popular library is called "link-preview-js", which is available on GitHub. This library allows you to generate link previews with customizable elements like the title, description, and image of the target link.
Another option is the "link-thumbnailer" library, 
Finally, there are also APIs available that can generate link previews, such as the Open Graph protocol and the Twitter Cards API. These APIs provide a standardized way of generating link previews that can be used across multiple platforms.