# How to implement facebook and g+ like link previews with client side languages

Tags: javascript, ajax, facebook, google-plus

What the real coding involved in making these link previews..means which languages? How can we extract meta tag information in a website. I know these all requires AJAX but I want a bit more clarification to make it for my website !!!

And one more important doubt is can I do it by just using client side languages like extracting meta tag dynamically by javascript function?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4646147/is-there-open-source-code-for-making-link-preview-text-and-icons-like-in-face

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I asked this question before, and got a good answer. [Is there open-source code for making 'link preview' text and icons, like in facebook?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4646147/is-there-open-source-code-for-making-link-preview-text-and-icons-like-in-face)

The solution there used AJAX and PHP - it links to this site: http://www.99points.info/2010/07/facebook-like-extracting-url-data-with-jquery-ajax-php/

Comment: Thanks sir Ben for your answer and good links. I got whole code on 99 points .Thanks Once again.

Answer (score 0):

See [Is there open-source code for making 'link preview' text and icons, like in facebook?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4646147/is-there-open-source-code-for-making-link-preview-text-and-icons-like-in-face)

As for the second part of the question: No, you can't because of the [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy).

Comment: Thanks sir Aaron You gave me a good link but I seriously want it on client-side. Ok then I will search into this matter some more and will come back if I get some good solution to my problem. Thanks Once again.

Comment: I'm wondering which part of "No" you didn't understand. To say it again: No client-only solution can do that. No browser can do that because it would expose them to very ugly security risks. So no, you can't do that, no browser can do it and no browser will ever be able to do it. You must do the processing on your server and then send the processed result to the client.

Answer (score 0):

Make a redirect page. Past the url into facebook and let it cache. Change redirect before you press post.