# Facebook link preview

Tags: jquery, .net, facebook, html

I am building a custom application and I would like to be able to do link previews like on Facebook. For example if you read an article copy the URL and post it on Facebook, you get a small preview in the post of what the website is and what's on it. Is there an API for this, or is it exclusive to Facebook?

Comment: Try here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4646147/is-there-open-source-code-for-making-link-preview-text-and-icons-like-in-face

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a tutorial after a basic google search.

http://www.ajaxtown.com/article/facebook-type-link-preview

It uses Ajax.

Comment: Answers should not just be links but explain the code in the answer.  The main reason is that links can go down so the answer becomes pointless.  This link currently does not work