# Create link previews on the client side, like in Facebook/LinkedIn

Tags: javascript, web-scraping

I am creating a web app with an input box where the user can write anything, including URLs. I want to create a link preview like Facebook and LinkedIn does:

[image]

Scrape the given URL and display its main image and heading, without a server round-trip. Is there a way to do this in the browser?

Comment: Recommendation questions are off-topic for [so]. Please describe exactly what you're trying to do and where you are having problems implementing it.

Comment: well i am building a webapp which has newsfeed and one part of it is showing preview of links. So whenever any change is made in input box i am checking if it contains a link and if it has I am making a http request sending the link and using node.io I am scrapping the link to get the Main image and text which I am sending in response. 
This method requires a lot of http calls..is there any way I can directly scrap the url from angular...?

Comment: @ArtjomB. Though the questions are bit similar, I've answered it in a different language(javascript) with my own code. I had also mentioned the link in my answer.I re asked the question as I felt it had no good answers for a particular language, and myself found/wrote a better answer.  Also that question is closed and hence won't accept new answers

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you what to do it on the client side, but then you provide an answer using node.js with jsdom. This is strange considering, you already said that it's working with node.io.

Comment: There is no real client-side only answer, since getting content from another domain violates cross-origin rules. Even the answers that route the link to a third party site just offload the server work to the third party site.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

After hours of googling I found the answer myself..
there is already a question in SO [Is there open-source code for making 'link preview' text and icons, like in facebook?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4646147/is-there-open-source-code-for-making-link-preview-text-and-icons-like-in-face) . So we can use this link http://api.embed.ly/1/oembed?url=YOUR-URL via http GET where we get the meta tags in json format..
I wrote my own code using [JSdom](https://github.com/tmpvar/jsdom) and here goes the code...

Server side code:

```
app.post( '/scrapUrl/', function( req, res ) {

    var jsdom = require( 'jsdom' );
    var jsonRes = {};
    jsdom.env( {
        url: req.body.url,
        scripts: [ "http://code.jquery.com/jquery.js" ],
        done: function( error, window ) {
          var $ = window.$;

          $( 'meta' ).each( function() {
            var name = $( this ).attr( 'property' );
            var value = $( this ).attr( 'content' );
            if ( name ) {
              jsonRes[ name.slice( 3 ) ] = value;
              console.log( name + ": " + value );
            }
          } );
          res.send( jsonRes );
        }
    } );
} );
```

and the angular code

```
$http.post( '/scrapUrl/', {
    url: url  //send the url U need to scrape
} ).then( function( res ) {
    console.log(res.data)//U get the meta tags as json object
});
```

Once you get the JSON object you can display it in whatever style you want.

Comment: Unfortunately, each request takes quite a long time using this method. At least 5-10 seconds per request.

Comment: @Fizzix It has been 2 years since I coded this, but AFAIR I just sent the url(the one which needs preview) to the server side to scrape it and sent back all those required meta tags to the client side. So, the request time depends on where you are hosting your server and how fast it is.

Comment: I know this is an old post of 1year+, but have you now, by any chance found a better way of doing this in a more promising manner?

Comment: this is not open source solution IMO

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you can generate link previews completely on the client, which is how link previews should be generated anyway, for efficiency and to avoid DOS-ing your server.

To find a client-side library that does link previews, [search GitHub for "link preview", and narrow down the search to JavaScript](https://github.com/search?l=JavaScript&q=link+preview&type=Repositories).