# How to generate a Facebook like Website preview for sharing?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, ionic-framework, frontend

I am developing a mobile application in **Ionic**. I have a share button where the user can share a website link. I want to have a feature where the user can preview the website as we can see in Facebook.

I tried most of the links [here](https://www.quora.com/Are-there-any-web-APIs-that-for-any-web-page-will-return-a-summary-and-the-most-important-image-on-the-page), but none of them work cleanly.

On the backend I have a *Play server*, and in the front end I am using *Ionic* and *AngularJS*.

Can anybody suggest me some good APIs that I can use?

Comment: Read this article: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/android

Comment: You could use something like: https://github.com/senorcris/opengraphjs but I don't know if it's production ready

Comment: @JCBorlagdan This is for sharing in Facebook. I have an app which is like Facebook.

Comment: @PritamBanerjee Oh I misread your statement. I guess when sending/receiving links you need to do send/read it as ng-html

Comment: [Possible duplicate here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24054691/how-to-create-link-previews-like-in-facebook-linkedin)

Answer (score 0):

You will need to read about web-scraping. I'd suggest to use this:

https://github.com/rchipka/node-osmosis

Or, this:

https://github.com/lapwinglabs/x-ray

Osmosis has problems with documentation, but at the end of the day, it quite simple, and it works good. X-ray has better docs, but has problems with encoding, so if you intend to scrape non-utf-8 websites, then consider to use osmosis.